# How to simulate a html page link click with Java?

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, click

There is a link on a html page with the following text

```
<Html>
...
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function hide() {
    createCookie("ABC","1","7");
    document.location='abc.php';
}
</script>

<a style="color:#000;" rel="nofollow" href="abc.php?x=1" onclick="hide();return false;">My Link</a>
...
```

How to use Java to simulate a html "My Link" click ?

Comment: What do you mean "with Java"? What do you mean by "simulate", for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which features a JavaScript evaluator and can thus work with in-page scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the aforementioned HtmlUnit, you might use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). At a company where I worked, we used it both for testing our web applications and for crawling javascript-based websites.